# Why Math Jax sans-serif in Opera, but serif in Fire-fox?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I screen-shot [Continuous Functions map compact sets to compact sets. Modus operandi of proof (Abbott p 115 t4.4.2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/778743/85079). I want serif as in Fire-fox.

[image]

Comment: Does this only happen on stackexchange sites?  If not, it's off-topic here, but maybe might be askable on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm confused! In the screenshot, I see a serif font in Opera, and a sans-serif font in Firefox. If that's not confusing enough, I see a serif font when using Firefox myself.

Comment: It looks like *all* your fonts in Firefox are sans-serif.  Do you have your preferences set to prevent page-specific fonts in Firefox?  That would certainly prevent MathJax from using its normal math fonts.